# other gesture API in android

Tags: android, gesture

i was just wondering as is there any other API or framework to work with gestures in android than the original API introduced in android because the one used in android is really not working when it is to be used for lines (although works pretty well for alphabets and signs)?
so any suggestions?
Thanks